# Error trying to create a webapi in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I get this message in the terminal:

> error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 5.6.3)'
> for 'net5.0'

I tried to run dotnet restore as it reccomended but it will not restore

Answer (score 52):

Just got the same issue on a clean machine.
I managed to fix it running the command:

```
dotnet nuget add source --name nuget.org https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

After that, create/restore your project and it should work.

[source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21920#issuecomment-629738708)

Comment: this was the issue, why no one tells us this in the documentation ?

Comment: Had the same issue with the installation provided by Rider IDE. The command above resolved the issue.

Comment: I had a similar error, `...ToDoAPI.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 6.4.0)' for 'net8.0'.` ... but this solution still fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to build an API using dotnet CLI as well, for a couple of days now. Ended up getting no answer from microsoft, or another source of info.

Anyways, the only way I made it work was unstalling .NET SDK 5.0.203 (Latest version for the time being), and installing [.NET SDK 5.0.101](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.101-windows-x64-installer), and thats it, new api command works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure your `.csproj` file looks a little bit like this?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the missing of the nuget packages. I had the same problem.
Try these steps:

1. Install the matching Nuget version from https://www.nuget.org/downloads
2. If you already created a project, try adding --force after the new sln and web api creation commands to update the files.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THESE STEPS

Step1 open Nuget Manager console

Step2 PM> get-help NuGet

Step3 PM> Update-Package
it will restore all file of Nuget Manager

---

RESON BEHIND

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3"

THIS package is not load properly